# Can we use Spring Boot to expose Rest API's for Spark Jobs?

Tags: spring-boot, apache-spark, hive

I have been given an task where I have the Apache Spark SQL and they want me to expose out the result as SPring REST API's using Spring Boot.

Is this possible? What I would be given would be Spark SQL's.

The Data currently runs on our DataBricks, But then the data also needs to be exposed as REST API's.

Comment: For spring boot and spark  see : https://docs.spring.io/spring-hadoop/docs/current/reference/html/springandhadoop-spark.html.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can do that. You can look up for Spring Spark integration.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-hadoop/docs/current/reference/html/springandhadoop-spark.html

Also, you can look at this question for more references.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-hadoop/docs/current/reference/html/springandhadoop-spark.html